# How do I select an attribute which is a sibling to the maximum in a JSON array with jq?

Tags: json, filter, aggregate-functions, jq

An API returns a JSON array like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Rangsdorf, Bahnhof",
    "lat": 52.294125,
    "lon": 13.431112
  },
  {
    "name": "Leipzig, Hauptbahnhof",
    "lat": 51.344817,
    "lon": 12.381321
  },
  {
    "name": "Senftenberg, Bahnhof",
    "lat": 51.52679,
    "lon": 14.003977
  },
 [...]
]
```

I'd like to retrieve that (or one) dict out of the array with the most northern position (i. e. where `lat` has a maximum) using `jq`. In the example, I'd expect either

```
{
  "name": "Rangsdorf, Bahnhof"
}
```

or, even better

```
  {
    "name": "Rangsdorf, Bahnhof",
    "lat": 52.294125,
    "lon": 13.431112
  }
```

as a result using `jq`.

Comment: easy solution with *jq*: `<file.json jq 'max_by(.lat)'`, or also an easy and invariant solution with `jtc`: `<file.json jtc -w'[lat]:<>G[-1]'`

Comment: Ok, thanks, that looks easy. Could you please i) briefly explain how this works and ii) post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `jq 'max_by(.lat)' input.json`

`max_by` is a function that  will scan a array and return the element that is the greater .

The type can be a string or a number .

You have more examples in the documentation https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions

some examples :

we have array of objects , we use a the property `p`

```
echo '[{"n":"a","p":1},{"n":"c","p":2},{"n":"b","p":8}]'| jq 'max_by(.p)'
{
  "n": "b",
  "p": 8
}
```

we have array of objects , we use a the property `n`

```
echo '[{"n":"a","p":1},{"n":"c","p":2},{"n":"b","p":8}]'| jq 'max_by(.n)'
{
  "n": "c",
  "p": 2
 }
```